# zip in cron doesn't work, but zip from command is working

Tags: backup, cron, compression

I need to back up a directory with

```
zip -r /savehere/backup_`date +%y%m%d%H%M%S` /save/this -q
```

It works fine. But not from crontab:

```
* * * * zip -r /savehere/backup_`date +%y%m%d%H%M%S` /save/this -q
```

neither

```
* * * * cd /savehere/; /usr/bin/zip -r /savehere/backup_`date +%y%m%d%H%M%S` /save/this -q
```

Оther commands in this crontab are working.

What is wrong with this command?

Comment: Cron needs to escape the % sign 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7068759/crontab-syntax-error/7068803#7068803

Comment: There is a cron log somewhere below /var/log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always use **/path/to/your/command** in your crons.

Provide complete path of your binary file in your crons.